# rmarkdown - define header with {.tabset} option dynamically inside loop?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Searched around and have not found an answer to this question. Basically, I want to loop over a vector of strings and for each string make it a heading with a tabset below it.

````
---
title: "report"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '4'
    toc_float: true
---

```{r}
headers <- c("membership", "participation")
tabs <- c("age", "gender")

for (i in headers){

    cat("###", i, "{.tabset}", "<br>", "\n")
    cat("\n", "<br>", "\n\n")

    for (j in tabs) {

        cat("####", j, "<br>", "\n")
        cat("\n", "<br>", "\n\n") 
    }
} 
```
````

which creates:

[image]

rather than:
[image]

which was created by:

````
---
title: "report"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '4'
    toc_float: true
---

### membership {.tabset}
```{r results='asis', echo = F}
tabs <- c("age", "gender")

for (j in tabs) {

        cat("####", j, "<br>", "\n")
        cat("\n", "<br>", "\n\n") 
    }

```

### participation {.tabset}
```{r results='asis', echo = F}

for (j in tabs) {

        cat("####", j, "<br>", "\n")
        cat("\n", "<br>", "\n\n") 
    }

```
````

e.g., hardcoding the headers that initiate the {.tabset}. Is it possible to create a header that initiates a tabset within a loop in rmarkdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice to see you, paqmo

I suggest you using `results = 'asis'` on option and remove `<br>` in code.

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
headers <- c("membership", "participation")
tabs <- c("age", "gender")

for (i in headers){

    cat("###", i, "{.tabset}", "\n")
    cat("\n\n\n")

    for (j in tabs) {

        cat("####", j, "\n")
        cat("\n\n\n") 
    }
} ```
````

And the result can be shown below
[image]